# ECharts: Can not find transform on type "filter"

Tags: javascript, echarts

This error happened while I was updating ECharts from 5.0.4 to 5.3.3. The same code worked well before, but in the newer version, it is not working. I have tried many ways (debugging, searching on the net, ...), and in the end, I even [downloaded](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=data-transform-filter&version=5.3.3&theme=dark) the example code from the official website of ECharts, but it shows the same error. What can be the reason for this error? Thanks!!

**Error Information:**

```
echarts.js:9213 Uncaught Error: Can not find transform on type "filter".
    at throwError (echarts.js:9213:11)
    at applySingleDataTransform (echarts.js:25603:7)
    at applyDataTransform (echarts.js:25567:20)
    at SourceManager._applyTransform (echarts.js:27211:22)
    at SourceManager._createSource (echarts.js:27153:29)
    at SourceManager.prepareSource (echarts.js:27095:14)
    at SourceManager._createSource (echarts.js:27120:23)
    at SourceManager.prepareSource (echarts.js:27095:14)
    at SeriesModel.init (echarts.js:27954:21)
    at GlobalModel.<anonymous> (echarts.js:21863:30)
```

Code:

```
var _rawData = '[["Income","Life Expectancy","Population","Country","Year"],[815,34.05,351014,"Australia",1800],[1314,39,645526,"Canada",1800],[985,32,321675013,"China",1800],[864,32.2,345043,"Cuba",1800], ...]';

var option = {
    dataset: [
      {
        id: 'dataset_raw',
        source: _rawData
      },
      {
        id: 'dataset_since_1950_of_germany',
        fromDatasetId: 'dataset_raw',
        transform: {
          type: 'filter',
          config: {
            and: [
              { dimension: 'Year', gte: 1950 },
              { dimension: 'Country', '=': 'Germany' }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        id: 'dataset_since_1950_of_france',
        fromDatasetId: 'dataset_raw',
        transform: {
          type: 'filter',
          config: {
            and: [
              { dimension: 'Year', gte: 1950 },
              { dimension: 'Country', '=': 'France' }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
.....
}
```

The code I have used to work is copied from the example code of the Official website, my own data has the same structure, just to be sure that the problem is not with the data I first want the official code to work, and then use on my own dataset, but still the example code not working.

Comment: Can you show your code where you configure the dataset transform?

Comment: Are you passing `_rawData` as a string, it looks like its JSON and should go through `JSON.parse` first.  `dataset.source` should be an array.

Comment: @DaveMeehan I have parsed it, that data is just what data looks like, the data will come from the internet in JSON format, I did not hard code the data, it was just to show how data looks like.

Comment: Thanks, I'm none the wiser.  I can't get the example to fail by messing with the `source` option, so doesn't appear to be related to the data.  I can only think that there is something malformed in your config.  What happens if you set the source to an empty array? (`source: []`).  What happens if you comment out one or both of the transform datasets?

Comment: @DaveMeehan Hmm, I have tried it both, when I commented on the transform part it shows this error:  `Error: Invalide sourceFormat: unknown` and when I used an empty array ([]), then it shows the same error as I mentioned in the question, I don't know if it is a bug with this version. An older version (which I have 5.0.4) is working, but I need some API that is in the newer version (5.3.3).

Comment: Can you post the complete code, but with a static subset of the data?

Comment: @DaveMeehan The link in the question I provided is complete code, I just used that code and data, nothing added or subtracted. You can try that code with its data using version 5.3.3 and see the result.

Comment: Are you saying that the linked example doesn't work on 5.3.3 (you can toggle the version in the example and it works for all).  If the same code doesn't work on your system, then I'd be looking at your setup (node version, dependencies) to see what might be amiss.  Can you try making a runnable example on a different system, perhaps one of the REPL/code bin sites?

Comment: @DaveMeehan Thanks! I tested the online version seems OK, but in my project is not working, and the older version is working well with the same data and the same dependencies, The code is all the same online example, I have copy and paste it, older version works, newer no. If there was any problem with my copy/paste the older one also won't work. So the code is just the example code, so no need to copy and paste long codes here, so there is no change in it with the online example.

Comment: @DaveMeehan till now, I did not write my own code, I first want the example to work, and then start writing my own code. But the example code works only in the older version but not in the newer version. All with the same dependencies nothing more nothing less.